# Berkowitz test for CVaR backtesting

Tags: risk-management, backtesting, cvar, validation

I want to test CVaR using the Berkowitz test (focus on the left tail). I have a couple of doubts:

1. Do I need to transform only actual losses that are above CVaR;
2. In the first transformation, whether the mean and variant parameters of the F (L)  of the risk model are used or whether these two parameters are calculated on the basis of the variables being transformed;
3. in the LR, whether the mean and variance of the new normal variables are used or are data related to the F (L) generated by the risk model.

Comment: Sorry I don't know the "Berkowitz test". Is it the one in the paper Testing Density Forecasts w/ Apps to Risk Management  JBES 2001 ? http://www.ims.nus.edu.sg/Programs/econometrics/files/kw_ref_2.pdf